# How can I separate items extracted from a YAML document into separate documents?

Tags: yaml, yq

I'm trying to extract items from an array in a YAML document, and have each item become its own standalone document, and print all documents together separated by `---`.

For example, assuming the following given YAML document:

```
kind: testDoc
items:
- kind: subDoc
  key: value1
- kind: subDoc
  key: value2
- kind: subDoc
  key: value3
```

I'd like to receive this:

```
kind: subDoc
key: value1
---
kind: subDoc
key: value2
---
kind: subDoc
key: value3
```

I've tried this: `yq '.items[]' < test.yaml` which yields this result:

```
kind: subDoc
key: value1
kind: subDoc
key: value2
kind: subDoc
key: value3
```

Is there a way to separate each result into a separate YAML document in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) (tested on v4.35.1), you can use the `split_doc` function (see the [manual](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/split-into-documents#split-array)).

```bash
yq '.items[] | split_doc' test.yaml
```

With [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) (tested on v3.2.3), use the `-y` option (see the [documentation](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq/#synopsis)).

```bash
yq -y '.items[]' test.yaml
```

With [itchyny/gojq](https://github.com/itchyny/gojq) (tested on v0.12.13), use the `--yaml-input` and `--yaml-output` options (see the [documentation](https://github.com/itchyny/gojq#difference-to-jq)).

```bash
gojq --yaml-input --yaml-output '.items[]' test.yaml
```

All of them have the same output (but gojq additionally sorts the keys):

```yaml
kind: subDoc
key: value1
---
kind: subDoc
key: value2
---
kind: subDoc
key: value3
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! (I'm using [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq))